# Regular expression matching c# without some tags

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match exact and prefix wildcard match but there's one condition that It should not be surrounded by a particular tag.

For example: if the word to match is `test`, the regular expression should match
`test`, `testing`,`tester` ,`testing.aspx` but it should not match `test</x>` and `testing</x>`, `tester</x>` and other words with prefix `test`

I came up with a regex which is matching `test</x>` too.

```
string regex = string.Format("\\b{0}(\\S)*(?!</x>)", "test");
```

Can somebody help me in correcting my regex?

Comment: Try `string regex = string.Format(@"\b{0}(?!</x>)\S*", "test");`

Comment: _There's space after x in the tag as somehow I don't know how to add tag which doesn't disappear when I post_, use backticks (``). So `text</x>`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated the ques with one more case it should also not match `testing</x>`. You expression works for 1st but fails for 2nd? Anything else I can do?

Comment: What is the source of your string you are Regexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\btest(\S)*(?!</x>)` pattern matches `test</x>` because `\btest` finds a word starting with `test`, then matches and repeatedly captures any 0+ non-whitespace chars, and then checks if there is no `</x>` immediately to the right of the current location. Since `(\S)*` matches the whole `</x>` at once the negative lookahead checks for `</x>` when the regex index is already placed after this `</x>` - and thus it returns true and the match is a success.

Yo may use

```
string regex = string.Format(@"(?>\b{0}[^<\s]*)(?!</x>)", "test");
// or, beginning with C#6   
// var regex = $@"(?>\b{SearchWord}[^<\s]*)(?!</x>)";
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3e%5cbtest%5b%5e%3c%5cs%5d*%29%28%3f!%3c%2fx%3e%29&i=if+the+word+to+match+is+test%2c+the+regular+expression+should+match+test%2c+testing%2c+testing.aspx+but+it+should+not+match+test%3c%2fx%3e+and+testing%3c%2fx%3e)

Now, it will match like this:

- `(?>\btest[^<\s]*)` - an atomic group matching

  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `test` - search term
  - `[^<\s]*` - 0+ chars other than `<` and whitespace
- `(?!</x>)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `</x>` char sequence immediately to the right of the current location

Comment: How do I make sure it doesn't matches something like `testing</x>`

Comment: I mean it should match `testing` but not `testing</x>`

Comment: So I used testing just as an example. There can be any word like tester, tests. The main word is just a prefix. Sorry for the confusion.